# ATL library unregister error

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I am building a COM dll using Visual Studio 2015 and started getting debug assert messages when the module is unregistered using regsvr32.  I am perplexed by this, have never had a problem with the rgs files.

Here is the rgs file (looks pretty standard to me):

```
HKCR
{
  NoRemove CLSID
  {
    ForceRemove {36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E} = s 'PropertyHandler Class'
    {
      ForceRemove Programmable
      InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
      {
        val ThreadingModel = s 'Both'
      }
      TypeLib = s '{D76FE9E8-1C33-4616-8F61-9E1C734843D9}'
      Version = s '1.0'
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the debug output when running regsvr32 /u against the dll:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1634) : atlTraceRegistrar - Deleting Key Programmable
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1634) : atlTraceRegistrar - Deleting Key InprocServer32
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1634) : atlTraceRegistrar - Deleting Key TypeLib
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1634) : atlTraceRegistrar - Deleting Key Version
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1634) : atlTraceRegistrar - Deleting Key {36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\atlmfc\include\statreg.h(1118) : atlTraceRegistrar - Should not be here!!
Debug Assertion Failed!
```

Here's what's in the registry under that key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}]
@="PropertyHandler Class"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}\InprocServer32]
@="[path to dll]"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}\Programmable]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}\TypeLib]
@="{D76FE9E8-1C33-4616-8F61-9E1C734843D9}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{36A078F3-BCD2-4777-B8E7-1AE96313113E}\Version]
@="1.0"
```

This project has 3 rgs files (one for each class) and all 3 are generating these debug asserts.  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Ought to be pretty obvious when you look at statreg.h line 1118.  It is finding extra sub-keys in the registry, ones it did not create.   So it can't implement `ForceRemove` safely.  You'll have to take a look-see with Regedit.exe to have a guess where they came from.

Comment: That's what is so odd, there aren't any extra sub-keys in those locations.  I edited my post to show what is actually in the registry before calling regsvr32 /u

Comment: Is this really a 64-bit server?  Have a look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\

Comment: Yup, 64-bit.  Nothing in the Wow nodes.